# Modify websites with Firefox Add-on

Tags: javascript, html, firefox-addon, overlay, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm writing a Firefox Add-on that modifies some specific websites when I open them. But I don't like the API at all. 
For example if I want to add a div-container that contains a button to a tab. It would look about like this:

```
var myScript = 'document.body.innerHTML += "<div style=background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);position:fixed;width:300px;height:300px;right:0px;top:0px;><input type=button value=test></input></div>";';
tab.attach({ contentScript: myScript });
```

This is:
1. Completely unreadable.
2. Will look different on lots of websites because some websites add default styles to all input-elements.

So is there a more readable way to modify a website that doesn't require to add a script as a string?
And is there a way to overlay any element on the website (even flash)?

Comment: to complete overwrite the page you have to change the document.html before any script loads.

Comment: I want to create a div container that overlays all other elements, so that it is always on top. I don't want to overwrite the sourcecode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`contentScriptFile`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/tabs.html#attach%28options%29).

And then you should use DOM APIs that don't suck performance and "shoot yourself in the foot"-wise (that are not `.innerHTML`), something like:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)";
...
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.setAttribute("type", "button");
...
div.appendChild(input);
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/) has the documentation.

As for styles: This one is tougher. Usually people will not inject DOM nodes into the page itself (not just because of CSS compatibility, but to avoid conflicts in Javascript and/or the DOM), but instead create an `<iframe>` which then has it's own set of CSS rules and own Javascript environment and is even subject to the same origin policy, which will hinder the website to mess with the contents, if done right.

Comment: That sounds great, thank you! But I don't really understand how I could use iframe to display my div-container. I mean I don't have a link that I could put in the iframe because I'm generating the code.

Comment: There is a bug problem with the contentScriptFile: The code that I'm adding to the websites is dynamically generated.

Comment: Do not generate content scripts dynamically! Have a static content script, and pass it dynamically generated data that it will use to make appropriate changes via [some form of message passing](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/communicating-with-other-scripts.html)

Comment: Hmm why? The script only needs to be generated once. Creating a way to communicate with the created script sounds kind of inefficient and overkill since I'd only need to communicate once with it.

Comment: First of all: You yourself rightly complained that this is totally unreadable. Then, string-concatenating stuff together and calling the equivalent of `eval()` on the result asks for trouble and/or security issues... Something like this isn't exactly easily maintainable, either... If you really have to, XHR (`request` module) the URI of your user script and string replace the stuff you need to dynamically create. But don't complain later if some addons.mozilla.org editor rejects your add-on for dynamically string-concatenating user scripts together; you have been warned ;)